# Rails: Undefined method create for nil class

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a sample project but when I am trying to create a new post getting an error **"undefined method create for nil class"**

My code is as follows.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :post, dependent: :destroy
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = current_user
    if @user.post.blank?
      @post = @user.post.create(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
    end
    redirect_to user_root_path
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([current_user, current_user.build_post]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But after trying so many times i have made some changes and it started working but i dont know what is the difference between both the codes.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = current_user
    if @user.posts.blank?
      @post = @user.posts.create(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
    end
    redirect_to user_root_path
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([current_user, current_user.posts.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

my routes.rb is

```
UserBlog::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'home#index'
end
```

Please help me and tell me what is the difference between both the codes ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The difference is in the helper methods that are added allowing you to build or create a new association object. The approach is slightly different for a `has_one` compared to a `has_many` association.

For a [`has_one` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) the method to create a new associated object would be `user.create_post`.

For a [`has_many` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) the method to create a new associated object would be `user.posts.create`.

Comment: thanks for this..i was using the has_many association syntax.